# Scheduling RSpec tests on Mac without the use of Ruby gems

Tags: macos, rspec, scheduling, automator

I've been trying to find a way to set a schedule for a suite of RSpec tests which would take hours to finish. The problem is on my work environment we can't just add whatever gems we like such as Rufus to the gemfile. So, is there way to do this with Mac's Automator, or a simpler way to write a script manually that runs at a specific time?

Comment: the `at` command ( `man at`)  will allow you to schedule a job for later

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/43678/mac-os-x-at-command-not-working about enabling it (might not be possible given your constraints)   Might also want to ask on super